# Increasing angle of rotation around center with sin and cos Canvas Js

Tags: javascript, canvas, trigonometry

Hy everyone,
i'm making some little exercices in canvas with sin and cos. I can now make a point rotating around another one with the angle incrementation in the animate function it work, like in the code below. My purpose is to put angle incrementation in the update function of the Class viefinder

```js
const canvas= document.getElementById('canvas');
const c= canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width= window.innerWidth;
canvas.height= window.innerHeight;

let angle=0;
const r=200;



/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                 View Finder                                */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

class ViewFinder {
  constructor(x,y,radius,color){
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
      this.radius=radius;
      this.color=color
      this.r= r;
      this.angle=angle;
      this.dx = this.r * Math.cos(this.angle);
      this.dy= this.r * Math.sin (this.angle);

  }
  draw(){
        //point 1
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius, 0, Math.PI *2,false )
        c.fillStyle=this.color;
        c.fill();
        //point 2
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x + this.dx, this.y + this.dy,this.radius,0, Math.PI * 2, false );
        c.fillStyle=this.color;
        c.fill();
  }
  update(){
      this.draw();
  }

}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                   Animate                                  */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

let animationId;



function animate(){
   animationId= requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   c.fillStyle='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
   c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   // calculate velocity
   viewFinder = new ViewFinder (canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 40, 'white');
   angle +=0.1/2;
   viewFinder.update();
}

animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So if i do the same but i put angle incrementation in the update function nothing move.. just try to understand why many thanks for yours answers

```js
const canvas= document.getElementById('canvas');
const c= canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width= window.innerWidth;
canvas.height= window.innerHeight;

let angle=0;
const r=200;



/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                 View Finder                                */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

class ViewFinder {
  constructor(x,y,radius,color){
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
      this.radius=radius;
      this.color=color
      this.r= r;
      this.angle=angle;
      this.dx = this.r * Math.cos(this.angle);
      this.dy= this.r * Math.sin (this.angle);

  }
  draw(){
        //point 1
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius, 0, Math.PI *2,false )
        c.fillStyle=this.color;
        c.fill();
        //point 2
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x + this.dx, this.y + this.dy,this.radius,0, Math.PI * 2, false );
        c.fillStyle=this.color;
        c.fill();
  }
  update(){
      this.draw();
      this.angle +=0.1;
  }

}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                   Animate                                  */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

let animationId;



function animate(){
   animationId= requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   c.fillStyle='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
   c.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   // calculate velocity
   viewFinder = new ViewFinder (canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, 40, 'white');
   viewFinder.update();
}




animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the first example, you are updating the global variable `angle`, but in the second you are updating `this.angle`

Comment: so i try to use angle in the constructor and the updating but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is:
In the first example, you are updating the global variable `angle`, but in the second you are updating `this.angle`,
In the first case, you are recreating the object `viewFinder` each frame, and since the value of `angle` is changed, the values of both `dx` & `dy` are re-calculated for the new object.

However, in the second case you are also recreating the object `viewFinder`, which uses the global variable `angle` to set the new angle and `dx` and `dy`
but you are not updating the angle anymore, which makes the element look static,
To fix this:

1. don't recreate the object for each frame, create it once and update it for each frame.
2. update the value of `dx` and `dy` after updating the value of `this.angle`

your code will look something like:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

let angle = 0
const r = 200

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                 View Finder                                */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

class ViewFinder {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.radius = radius
    this.color = color
    this.r = r
    this.angle = angle
    this.dx = this.r * Math.cos(this.angle)
    this.dy = this.r * Math.sin(this.angle)
  }
  draw() {
    //point 1
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    c.fillStyle = this.color
    c.fill()
    //point 2
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(
      this.x + this.dx,
      this.y + this.dy,
      this.radius,
      0,
      Math.PI * 2,
      false
    )
    c.fillStyle = this.color
    c.fill()
  }
  update() {
    this.draw()
    this.angle += 0.1
    this.dx = this.r * Math.cos(this.angle)
    this.dy = this.r * Math.sin(this.angle)
  }
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                   Animate                                  */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

let animationId

let viewFinder = new ViewFinder(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 40, 'white')
function animate() {
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  c.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  // calculate velocity

  viewFinder.update()
}

animate()
```

Comment: thank Abd your explication is perfect now i understand that i have to change dx and dy position, in fact redraw for every frame the viewFinder was not a good practice